# Getting JSON encoded values in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, ajax

I am retrieving data from database. When I try to output it in console using `console.log(response)`, I would get this:

```
Array
(
    [deptCode] => Econ
    [collegeCode] => BA
    [deptName] => Economics
)
```

I am expecting to get the values `Econ, BA, and Economics`.

My problem is when I pass it from PHP to AJAX using `response["deptCode"]`, I would get `undefined`.

I have tried doing `data = JSON.parse(response);` and I would get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I've also tried this:

```
for(var key in response){
    console.log(response[key]);
}
```

but the result is this:
[image result from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31qSC.png)

Here's my `db.php`:

```
public function getDept($code){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM department WHERE "deptCode" = :code';
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['code'=>$code]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
```

action.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_id'])){
    $id = $_POST['edit_id'];

    $row = $db->getDept($id);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

index:

```
$("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{edit_it:edit_id},
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //data = JSON.parse(response);
            //for(var key in response){
            //    console.log(response[key]);
            //}
        }
    })
})
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Check what the request was actually answered with, using your brower dev tools (network panel.)

Comment: Your database query probably didn’t return any records, because you are comparing the entered value against a _string_. If you wanted to look for it in the _column_ by the name `deptCode`, then of course the quotes around that need to go.

Answer (score -2):

I have `json_decode` in such as errors before.
to parse to JSON in ajax response, you have to decode the data in PHP.
i.e. Please use `json_decode` in PHP.
and then `JSON.parse(response)` in ajax response.
I hope that you will solve it.